# Why when I use slices with for loops it does not loop with only the items sliced?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to python and programming in general and I am trying to solve a problem where I have to make a function that adds "commas" and "and" to a list.But I can not use slices with for loops and I can not understand why.

```
c = ["x", "y", "z"]
def fu(l):
    g = ""
    for i in l[0:-1]:
        g = str(l) + ", "
        return g
print(fu(c))
```

What I expected from this code was to return:
x,y z

But I got:
['x', 'y', 'z'],

Comment: There're various problems with this code. You should probably check python tutorial and try to figure out problems by your own. [`for` Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), [Built-in Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#built-in-types).

Comment: You set `g = str(l)`. Why do you expect it to be a slice of `l` when you use the original `l`?

Comment: are you looking to just do `",".join(["x", "y", "z"])`?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi AH you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c = ["x", "y", "z"]
def fu(l):
    g = ""
    for i in l:
        if(l[-1]!=i):
            g += str(i) + ", "
        else:
            g+=str(i)
    return g
print(fu(c))
```

you were returning at the start, had an incorrect iterator and one other issue
Here is the working code, let me know if you need further explanation on any of it

Comment: `str(i)` is useless if element is already a string

Comment: I tried running your code but it gave me x,y,z, while I am trying to achieve x,y z

Comment: Olvin I agree with you but wanted to keep the code as similar to the original as possible

Answer (score 0):

What I get from your question is you want all the elements appended to a string with ',' except the last one, the last one will be appended using a space. Here is the code for you:

```
c = ["x", "y", "z"]

out = ", ".join(c[0:-1])
out += " "+c[-1]
print (out)
```

Output:

```
x, y z
```

Comment: Yes, the output is correct, but my problem was to make a function that added "commas" to every type of list. I already solved the problem but thanks for the answer.